How to print/log on console when running benchmarks?
I am trying to benchmark pallet_democracy specifically the veto_external extrinsic for my runtime and during the initial setup I need to log into the console. Maybe a print statement that says "Initial setup started" or printing some values. How do I achieve this? I am adding the log crate as a dependency and have included it in the features section as shown.
[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
      "log/std"
]

I am doing this in the following dependency checkout
/home/rrr/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/1747353/frame/democracy/src/benchmarking.rs

and adding a log statement like below.
benchmarks! {
   veto_external{
       log!(info, "Initial setup starts");
              }
}

But when I run the benchmark for my runtime I do not see any log.

log = { version = "0.4.17", default-features = false } . Do you import it?

What types of benchmarking are you running? cargo test --features runtime-benchmarks or from the node CLI?
